# Override cluster url when spark-submitting

Tags: apache-spark

I wrote a Spark application that is packaged by SBT as a JAR. The JAR shall be deployed on a cluster. I also want to be able to run the program with `sbt run` in local mode. Currently I use

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master(args(0))
      .getOrCreate()
```

to create my `SparkSession`. Can I just write `.master("local")` and override the `"local"` by using `--master myclusterurl` in my `./bin/spark-submit` command?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--master` url and `SparkConf`:

```
SparkSession.builder.config(new SparkConf()).getOrCreate
```